# React unique key on components that don't have unique fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have something that requires a user to provide me a list of timeframes. One field is a number (1,2,3), the other field is the timeUnit (minute, hour, second). This is a list, so React requires a unique key. I cannot find anything online that shows how to create a unique key, or a hash, from that component itself. Using the index of the array obviously does not work, as the user can remove from the center of the list. But using the fields of the component is no good as well, because it is very possible to have an overlap in number and timeUnit (if only for a brief second).[image]

Any suggestions on how to create a unique key for this situation?

Comment: Just use a running number. The key doesn't need to be globally unique, just locally. Reversability, uniformness, and all these don't matter either, so a hash is overkill as well.

Comment: can you define a running number? do you mean an incrementing index? thats the same thing as an array index?

Comment: No, it's not the same. If you e.g. create an array, and it has ids 0, 1, 2, then delete the middle, it will be 0, 2, which is not the index. If you insert one in the middle then, it would be 0, 3, 2, and so on. The problematic part of the index is, that when you insert or delete in the middle, all following elements' indices are shifted, so they are not the same as before anymore.

Comment: where/how would you store that id so the next time around, it knows what index belonged to what component? Right so if you return (array.map(<div key={runningNumber}>...</>), so that it can identify what the right running number would be?

Comment: In your data structure, whatever that is, typically on the array elements, e.g. the elements of `array` would get a new property, which holds the id. You don't show that much code, so i can't be sure, where in your structure it would be.

Comment: sounds like you would need some mapping, {component, key}, so that you can go map[component] to find the key?

Comment: you mean store the id as state within the component that is getting mapped? how would the higher level component which calls the map function have access to that? you can't go component.getState?

Comment: Typically, you `map` some array of data to components (again, i don't know anything about your structure, you don't show anything), like you say, `array.map(<div key={runningNumber}>...</>`. Often, these array elements already have data, which can be transformed to a unique id. In your case apparently not, so you artificially add one, and a running number (incrementing index if you so want) is just a really simple way to make one.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use timestamp. When user create a timeframes, unique it by Date.now()?

Comment: But where would you store what that id should be? upon each rerender, it needs to be retrieved. So you have to store it somewhere, so React can know to reuse that specific timestamp. so you still run into the issue of needing to create a unique key for a component

Comment: sounds like you need a hash id in backend。